# Blob from javascript binary string

Tags: javascript, string, binary, blob

I have a binary string created with `FileReader.readAsBinaryString(blob).`

I want to create a Blob with the binary data represented in this binary string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: @epascarello how can I use FileReader to solve my problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is the blob that you used not available for use anymore?
Do you have to use `readAsBinaryString`? Can you use `readAsArrayBuffer` instead. With an array buffer it would be much easier to recreate the blob.

If not you could build back the blob by cycling through the string and building a byte array then creating a blob from it.

```js
$('input').change(function(){
    var frb = new FileReader();
    frb.onload = function(){
        var i, l, d, array;
        d = this.result;
        l = d.length;
        array = new Uint8Array(l);
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){
            array[i] = d.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var b = new Blob([array], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
        window.location.href = URL.createObjectURL(b);
    };
    frb.readAsBinaryString(this.files[0]);
    
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me. I've edited your answer with code that worked for me. One difference from my original question is that in this case, binaryString came from a file using the node.js method fs.readFileSync(path, "binary").

Comment: This worked great for me! I just had to change one thing - i could not use the Uint8Array directly in the Blob constructor but had to pass new Blob([array.buffer]) instead, else the content of the Blob was just the serialized Uint8Array.