# Reading binary data from REST response

Tags: javascript, rest

I have REST service endpoint serving binary data (files e.g PDF, JPG, PNG etc)
REST service is secured with token based authentication.
Without security I could simply get PNG and open it in new window with

`<a href="RESTURL/item/1/file" target="_blank">`

But now, after we implemented security I get "Authorization error" because I have to pass "Authorization" header with "Bearer TOKEN"...

I thought of 2 solutions (I have ZERO experience with binary data, images etc.):

1.(naive) use existing endpoint to download binary data and open it like this:

`let uriContent = "data:image/jpg," + result;
    window.open(uriContent);`

where result is response from REST service returning binary data.

Doesn't work - I get jibberish in opened window

2. (not possible to try now) change REST service to return Base64 and open it with:

`let uriContent = "data:image/jpg;base64," + result;
    window.open(uriContent);`

3. Any other solutions ??? - I need to be able open new Tab with PNG/PDF etc. AND download it to disk also

Comment: Is it possible that the web service is returning some additional data that it wasn't before?  I can't see why your 1st solution wouldn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27810163/575527 - Three APIs: FileReader, Blob and Url.